# Код для вычисления наибольшего по длине слова в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа из введенной строки должна выписать все слова в столбик, а потом из этой строки выписать самое длинное слово, код для получения столбца слов уже готов, а вот как вручную сделать код для поиска самого большого слова я не знаю. 
  Помогите пожалуйста.
  Вот сам код:

```
str1 = str(input())
word = ""
words = []
k = 0

for i in str1:
 if i != " ":
  word += i
 else:  
  words.append(word)
  word = ""

for j in words:
 print(j)


for j in words:
 if j > words(k):  
  j += 1
 else:
  k += 1
```

Comment: Там есть ошибка - if j > words(k): , а должно быть: if j > words[k]:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запоминаем первый элемент, после простой пройдемся по списку сравнив следующие слова:

```
words = ['a', 'asa1', 'dd', '111']
max_len_word = words[0]

for i in range(1, len(words)):
    word = words[i]

    if len(word) > len(max_len_word):
        max_len_word = word

print(max_len_word)  # asa1
```

Аналогичный результат будет при использовании функции `max` с ключом `len`:

```
words = ['a', 'asa1', 'dd', '111']
print(max(words, key=len))
# asa1
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
def str_split(s):
  words = []
  buf = ''
  for char in s:
    if char == ' ':
      if buf:
        words.append(buf)
      buf = ''
    else:
      buf += char
  if buf:
    words.append(buf)
  return words


def words_print(words):
  for word in words:
    print(word)


def len_word(word):
  i = 0
  for _ in word:
    i += 1
  return i


def find_max(words):
  temp = 0, ''
  for word in words:
    word_length = len_word(word)
    if word_length > temp[0]:
      temp = word_length, word
  return temp[1]


words = str_split(input())
words_print(words)
print('Max:', find_max(words))
```

Comment: Я знаю, что этот код подходит, но мне нужен код программы, не включающий в себя такие функции как split или max, и тд.

Comment: @Михаил , почему бы не указать это в вопросе?

Comment: я надеюсь свои реализации строки и списка писать не надо?